# When would you use the mediator design pattern

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, mediator

As the title states when would you recommend the use of the [mediator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) and where do you see it used incorrectly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a mediator when the **complexity of object communication** begins to **hinder object reusability**.  This type of complexity often appears in view instances, though it could really be anywhere.

Misuse of a mediator can result in crippling the interfaces of the mediator's colleague classes.

It seems a little funny to talk about misusing a pattern.  If your implementation follows the pattern, then you've used the pattern.  Otherwise, you haven't.  In other words, if your mediator is doing something else, then it probably isn't a mediator.  Patterns are defined by what they do, what they in fact are.  The names of things are simply labels.

The real question to ask yourself is whether your implementation of a pattern fulfills the pattern's promises for your design.  The mediator pattern aims to encapsulate complex inter-object communication when it is becoming unmanageable.  If it hasn't accomplished this, or hasn't done it very well, you could say that a mediator is being misused.  At some point, it becomes a value judgement.

Comment: A misuse I have encountered is to create a huge Mediator class with a lot of logic in it.

Answer (score 3):

I have used it to deal with swing apps.

When I'm building a GUI I don't like each control knowing each other because that would require subclassing.

Instead I have a Main object which contains the listener and the widgets and let it mediate between the different controls, buttons, textfields etc.

Comment: I believe by the fact that you used the word "contains" here that this is actually not the Mediator pattern. It sounds more like the Facade pattern (or what I would call a Manager class). Mediator seems to be moreso having a shared class between 2 classes, perhaps that you pass from one to the other, or that you give a reference to to both classes, which then acts as an indirect connection between them.

Comment: And actually the shared class that you pass from one class to another sounds more like the Flyweight pattern lol. Idk I think maybe these definitions are too ambiguous and/or too tightly coupled to specific languages.

Answer (score 2):

The mediator is also basically what an event-pump is. A very common pattern in GUI's and Games.

Also I've used mediator before to communicate among very dispar systems, and legacy frameworks.

Comment: Event-Pump == Event-Hub, right? Just a bussing system, basically? Or rather Event-Driven Mediation (routes requests)?